Using VL53L3CX sensor and a BNO055 sensor with ESP32
I would like to use my ESP32 dev module to control the VL53L3CX-SATEL (STM ToF sensor) and the BNO055 (9 Axis IMU module from Adafruit) on the same I2C bus.
My future goal is to use multiple VL53L3CX but first i want to use these 2 together.
I already set up both sensors separately and they work fine, the problem is that when i try to use both in the same code, the code gets stuck somewhere in the init part, it detects the BNO055, but it skips the line where it should print the status of the VL53L3CX, and it does nothing more.
Plus if i scan for i2c adresses with another code, nothing shows when both are connected, unless i pull the 3v3 of the VL53L3CX, at that moment the program detects both devices (weird since it's not supposed to be powered without the 3v3).
I don't use any pull ups for sda and scl since the BNO055 already has them.
This is the code i use, with the STM32duino lib for vl53x, and the adafruit one for the bno055:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <vl53lx_class.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>

/* Set the delay between fresh samples */
uint16_t BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS = 100;


#define SDA_PIN 21  // Define your SDA pin number
#define SCL_PIN 22  // Define your SCL pin number

#define DEV_I2C Wire
#define SerialPort Serial

#ifndef LED_BUILTIN
#define LED_BUILTIN 13
#endif
#define LedPin LED_BUILTIN

// Define buffer sizes for each sensor
#define BUFFER_SIZE_SENSOR_1 128
#define BUFFER_SIZE_SENSOR_2 256

#define interruptPin 2

// Components.
Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55, 0x28, &DEV_I2C);
VL53LX sensor_vl53lx_sat(&DEV_I2C, 4);

volatile int interruptCount=0;

void measure()
{
   interruptCount=1;
}

void setup()
{

  VL53LX_Error status;

  // Set the pin mode to INPUT to disable internal pull-ups
  pinMode(SDA_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(SCL_PIN, INPUT);


  // Led.
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(interruptPin, measure, FALLING);

  // Initialize serial for output.
  SerialPort.begin(115200);
  SerialPort.println("Starting...");

  // Initialize I2C bus.
  DEV_I2C.begin(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);
  //sensor_vl53lx_2.VL53LX_SetDeviceAddress(0x55);

  Serial.print("BNO055 Detecté");
  DEV_I2C.setBufferSize(256); // Set smaller buffer if needed by BNO055

  // Configure VL53LX satellite component.
  sensor_vl53lx_sat.begin();

  // Switch off VL53LX satellite component.
  sensor_vl53lx_sat.VL53LX_Off();

  // Initialize VL53LX satellite component.
  status = sensor_vl53lx_sat.InitSensor(0x12);

  if(status)
  {
    SerialPort.println("Init sensor_vl53lx_sat failed...");
  }
  Serial.print(status);
  DEV_I2C.setBufferSize(128); // Set smaller buffer if needed by BNO055

    /* Initialise the sensor */
  if (!bno.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the BNO055 ... check your connections */
    Serial.print("Ooops, no BNO055 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
    while (1);
  }

  sensor_vl53lx_sat.VL53LX_StartMeasurement();

}

void loop() {
  VL53LX_MultiRangingData_t MultiRangingData;
  VL53LX_MultiRangingData_t *pMultiRangingData = &MultiRangingData;
  sensors_event_t orientationData;

  uint8_t NewDataReady = 0;
  int no_of_object_found = 0, j;
  char report[64];

  //server.handleClient();  // Traite les requêtes HTTP
  DEV_I2C.setBufferSize(256); // Set smaller buffer if needed by BNO055

  if (interruptCount) {
    int status;
    interruptCount = 0; // Reset the interrupt flag

    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH); // Indicate processing

    status = sensor_vl53lx_sat.VL53LX_GetMeasurementDataReady(&NewDataReady);
    if (!status && NewDataReady) {
      status = sensor_vl53lx_sat.VL53LX_GetMultiRangingData(pMultiRangingData);
      no_of_object_found = pMultiRangingData->NumberOfObjectsFound;
      snprintf(report, sizeof(report), "Count=%d, #Objs=%1d ", pMultiRangingData->StreamCount, no_of_object_found);
      SerialPort.print(report);
      for (j = 0; j < no_of_object_found; j++) {
        if (j != 0) SerialPort.print("\r\n                   ");
        SerialPort.print("Capteur 1: status=");
        SerialPort.print(pMultiRangingData->RangeData[j].RangeStatus);
        SerialPort.print(", D=");
        SerialPort.print(pMultiRangingData->RangeData[j].RangeMilliMeter);
        SerialPort.print("mm, Signal=");
        SerialPort.print((float)pMultiRangingData->RangeData[j].SignalRateRtnMegaCps / 65536.0);
        SerialPort.print(" Mcps, Ambient=");
        SerialPort.print((float)pMultiRangingData->RangeData[j].AmbientRateRtnMegaCps / 65536.0);
        SerialPort.print(" Mcps");
        
        
      }
      SerialPort.println("");

      if (status == 0) {
        sensor_vl53lx_sat.VL53LX_ClearInterruptAndStartMeasurement();
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
  }
  DEV_I2C.setBufferSize(128); // Set smaller buffer if needed by BNO055

  //retrieve BNO055 Data
  bno.getEvent(&orientationData, Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_EULER);
  Serial.print("Orientation = ");
  printEvent(&orientationData);
  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
}

void printEvent(sensors_event_t* event) {
  Serial.print("{");
  Serial.print("\"x\":"); Serial.print(event->orientation.x);
  Serial.print(", \"y\":"); Serial.print(event->orientation.y);
  Serial.print(", \"z\":"); Serial.print(event->orientation.z);
  Serial.print("}\n");
}
I

O2 for the GPIO1 pin (interrupt) of the VL53L3CX
IO4 for the XSHUT pin of the VL53L3CX
The VL53L3CX needs a buffer length and the BNO055 128 so i have to change them (i don't know if this is the right way because i can't test the code).
Any further debugging is tricky because the vl53l3cx doesn't provide any address list or lots of documentation. My second time using Arduino IDLE and ESP, normally i do just C programming with keil and i can manually work with the registers of the sensors.. I would like some help, thank you in advance!
Terminal output with my code](https://i.sstatic.net/EvHlYVZP.png)
